# MySQL correct way to join tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 separate tables: 'object' (id, name, model_id), 'object_model' (id, name, type_id) and 'object_type' (id, name).

How can I properly join these three to get the appropriate names from all the tables?

I'm trying to join by doing the following:

```
SELECT object.id AS id, object.name AS name, object_model.name AS model_name, object_type.name AS type_name 
FROM object 
LEFT JOIN object_model ON object_model.id = object.model_id 
LEFT JOIN object_type ON object_type.id = object.model_type_id
```

But get the error:

> "Unknown column 'object.model_type_id' in 'on clause'"

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Just a typo... `object_model.type_id` in the last line.

Comment: Error means that `object.model_type_id` column does not exist. If you need help, please provide schema, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column is called `object_model.type_id`. You have the dot and underscore in the wrong places.

```
LEFT JOIN object_type ON object_type.id = object_model.type_id
```

Otherwise, your query looks like it will do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

according to your information you do not have "model_type_id" in "object". What you have is "type_id" in "object_model". So I guess you should change

```
LEFT JOIN object_type ON object_type.id = object.model_type_id
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN object_type ON object_type.id = object_model.type_id
```